Asp.net это сложно
Столкнулся с проблемой
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityError', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'SportGym.ViewsModel.RegistrationViewModel
Требует модель которую я и так использую, как так почему так не пойму
Контроллер для логина и регистрации пользователя, ниже там пипец не могу поменять никак отдельно сделать html в  RegistrationViewModel 
по идее больше и неизачего проблемам быть, нажимаю кнопку Зарегистрироваться и на методе пост и вылазит ошибка
Вроде все написал
AccountController.cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<Clients> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<Clients> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<Clients> userManager, SignInManager<Clients> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
       
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
     
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false ,lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View("Login", model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return (IAuthenticationManager)HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var client = new Clients
            {
                FullName = model.FullName,
                Date = model.Date,
                Phone = model.Phone,
                Email = model.Email,
                Gender = model.Gender,
                Role = "Client",
                UserName = model.Email
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(client, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(client, isPersistent: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

            }
           
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                    
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    return View(error);
            } 
        }

        return View(model);
    }

RegistrationViewModel
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите ФИО")]
    [Display(Name = "ФИО")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите дату рождения")]
    [Display(Name = "Дата рождения (00.00.0000")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите телефон")]
    [Display(Name = "Телефон")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите адрес электронной почты")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Введите корректный адрес электронной почты")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите пол")]
    [Display(Name = "Пол")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите пароль")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Пароль должен быть от {2} до {1} символов", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Подтвердите пароль")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароль и подтверждение пароля не совпадают")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

Register.cshtml

```@model SportGym.ViewsModel.RegistrationViewModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Регистрация";
}```





<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Phone" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>


Пытался отправить ошибку, которой вроде нет, убрал вот это и всё заработало:
foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
                
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                return View(error);
        } 

